# How to get a variable from a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def checkQuota(candidateX_Votes, candidateX_Won):
    quota = int((validVotesCast / (seatsAvaliable + 1)) + 1)

    if candidateX_Votes < quota:
        candidateX_Won = False
        return candidateX_Won

    elif candidateX_Votes >= quota:
        candidateX_Won = True
        return candidateX_Won
```

The goal is to have the value of either true or false set as the variable that is put into the function, for example, if I do `checkQuota(candidateA_Votes, candidateA_Won)` I should be able to use `candidateA_Won` later on where it is either assigned the value of true or false.

Comment: Why are you passing `candidateX_Won` into the function if you are also using it as the return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't actually use `candidateA_Won` as a parameter, I would recommend you refactor to instead just return the value you want and store *that* in an external variable, as follows:

```
def checkQuota(candidateX_Votes): # Get rid of the parameter
    quota = int((validVotesCast / (seatsAvaliable + 1)) + 1)

    if candidateX_Votes < quota:
        candidateX_Won = False
        return candidateX_Won

    elif candidateX_Votes >= quota:
        candidateX_Won = True
        return candidateX_Won
```

Then, you can use the function as follows:

```
candidateX_Won = checkQuota(candidateX_Votes) # Without having to pass in a variable
```

In fact you can even simplify the function above to:

```
def checkQuota(candidateX_Votes):
    return not (candidateX_Votes < int((validVotesCast / (seatsAvaliable + 1)) + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

your variable `candidateX_Won` is local in the function scope. When you assign a `True` or `False` you change a local variable instead of the original one. To get the result you want, you can use this example:

```
def checkQuota(candidate_x_votes):
    # here you calculate/get validVotesCast and seatsAvaliable
    quota = int((validVotesCast / (seatsAvaliable + 1)) + 1)
    return not (candidate_x_votes < quota)  # this will return True or False

# and after that you can use your function
candidateX_Votes = 12 # for example 
candidateX_Won = checkQuota(candidateX_Votes)
```